# Want to create custom progress loader in flutter

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, flutter-design

I want to create the progress loader as displayed in this image.

The progress part should be the darker one with a blue pipe at the end.

**Expecting Result:**

[image]

I'm attaching the images with and without opacity if you need them.
[image: Image1] [image: Image2]

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you do something as a start please share the code here. It'll help you to get results first.

Comment: Here is a repo. It's a kind of progress loader. You can try to customize it yourself. https://github.com/rajaniket/pencil_loader